# How can i select the second checkbox on selecting the first checkbox?

Tags: vue.js

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="first" class="vh-item" value="first" v-model="checkedNames" />
<label class="list-specific" for="first">1stcheck</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="second" class="vh-item" v-model="checkedNames"
value="second"/>
<label class="list-specific" for="second">2ndcheck</label>
```

On selecting the first checkbox, How to select the second checkbox, Basically i am trying to do with above functionality/code.

Functionality is like, if click on first checkbox, second checkbox also need to select, and when i click the second checkbox alone, second checkbox only need to select. And i want to use the v-model as the same.

Do i need to write any click event to select both?

Comment: It is possible to select both the input with `v-model` as you've done but it is not possible to check only one if both are using `v-model="checkedNames"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more information about the context and other preconditions, I think this should work for you, simply listening for the change event of the first checkbox:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    checkedNames: []
  },
  methods: {
    firstChanged(ev) {
      if (ev.target.checked && !this.checkedNames.includes('second')) {
        this.checkedNames.push('second');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="checkbox" id="first" class="vh-item" value="first" v-model="checkedNames" @change="firstChanged" />
  <label class="list-specific" for="first">1stcheck</label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="second" class="vh-item" v-model="checkedNames" value="second" />
  <label class="list-specific" for="second">2ndcheck</label>
  
  {{ checkedNames }}
</div>
```